# Laravel Auth Failed?

Tags: php, laravel

I am creating a simple login page for my application but my auth always says i'm failed?

```
        $email = Input::get('email');
        //echo = matchesmyemail

        $password = Input::get('password');
        //echo = matchesmydbpassword


        $auth = Auth::attempt(array(
            'email' => $email,
            'password' => $password
        ));

        if($auth){
            die('logged in');
        }else{
            die('failed');
        }
```

Any ideas what i'm doing incorrect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is your password hashed in the database?

```
$password = Hash::make('password');
```

If you have a plain text password in the database table than that is the problem. The password will be hashed and the hashes will be compared.

Comment: Can i not use plain text?

Comment: You **should not** use plain text - it's a major security risk! If anyone gets access to your database, they will then have access to **everyone's** password.